# how to deal with loop interactive input commands in subprocess, python

Tags: python

A example of the loop interactive input commands is, `jupyter notebook password`  in cmd.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjlhd.png)

I want to type the password twice by program rather than mannual method, however, both methods A and B are not viable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whh34.png)

method A

```
import subprocess
 
p = subprocess.Popen("jupyter notebook password", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8") 
stdout, stderr = p.communicate('123456\n') 
stdout, stderr = p.communicate('123456\n')
```

method B

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("jupyter notebook password", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8")   #,universal_newlines=True
p.stdin.flush()   
p.stdin.write("123456\n")
p.stdin.flush()   
p.stdin.write("123456\n")
p.stdin.flush()
```

The expection is, "Wrote hashed password to xxxxxxxx"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTkuZ.png)